# Recover environment properties sent to EJB

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, initial-context, josso

I have a Delegate that instanciate the corresponding Bean sending credentials (Josso Authentication) through InitialContext [as shown here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#InitialContext(java.util.Hashtable)).

At Bean, I've tried to recover Josso Data with SessionContext, as shown below:

```
@Resource private SessionContext context;
```

The problem I'm facing is that I couldn't retrieve Josso Data at Bean scope. I've tried "context.getEnvironment()" but this method is deprecated and I didn't find any alternative.

In order to find a solution, I've tried:

```
context.lookup(JNDI_BEAN_NAME);
context.lookup("java:comp/env/JNDI_BEAN_NAME")
context.lookup("java:comp/env")
```

But the two first commands only return me the Bean itself and the last one only return me global variables.

What is the correct alternative to "context.getEnvironment()"?

Comment: What do you think `context.getEnvironment()` used to return? It is an EJB 1.0 API that was deprecated in EJB 1.1. It was replaced with the `<env-entry>` elements in the ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor

Comment: You will not be able to recover "credentials", however you can get the authenticated identity of the user by injecting a security principal: `@Resource java.security.Principal principal` or via SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().

Comment: My EJB configuration doesn't include ejb-jar.xml. About your suggestion, can I also recover password or jossoId via SessionContext? I need this to have a authenticated bean

Comment: I have a filter and at that time I have all this info (user, password, jossoid) and I've added these attributes at session. I need at least JossoId on my Bean. Any suggestion?

Comment: The security context will be propagated from your web app to your EJBs and other managed beans if you have integrated Josso correctly with your application server.

Answer (score 0):

`java:comp/env` finds container-managed resources only and is read-only at runtime. If you want, you can expose a local interface that gets Josso credentials from the delegate.

```
@Local
public interface AuthenticatorLocal {
    void getJossoCredentials();
}
```

Otherwise, you can just use `context.getCallerPrincipal()`.

Comment: your idea guided me to an alternative solution, thanks for sharing. In fact, I had all the data I needed with a class of our fundation that gave me Josso Data.